# Relative "SourceCodeDirectory" project variable file path does not work on FinalBuilder

Tags: build, finalbuilder, continuous-build, finalbuilder7

I am trying to build a project on our build machine. I've set the `SourceCodeDirectory` project variable file path to `%FBPROJECTDIR%\..\..\..\ProjectFolderName`

This relative path moves back 3 directories, but does not seem to work when the variable is being used elsewhere in FinalBuilder, e.g `%SourceCodeDirectory%`

I have tried checking the *"Make Available As Environment Variable"* option as well as the *"Macro (Expand variable references on each access)"* option.

What do I need to do to make FinalBuilder recognize my *SourceCodeDirectory* path?

I don't want to specify the exact path in order to leave it generic.

Thank you.

**Additional Info**

Final Builder version: 7.0.0.1561

Comment: TIP: Ask any FinalBuilder questions on FinalBulder forum. They will answer it way faster and with more precision than here.